# Reverse Javascript Capitalized

Tags: javascript, html

enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19pZe.jpg)

How to make observe the Capital word behavior ?

source code :
`enter code here`

```
document.getElementById("btnReverse").onclick = function () {
  reverse();
};

String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, replacement) {
  if (index >= this.length) {
    return this.valueOf();
  }

  return this.substring(0, index) + replacement + this.substring(index + 1);
};

function reverseWord(word) {
  let wordLength = word.length;
  let reversedWord = word;
  for (let j = 0; j < wordLength / 2; j++) {
    let temp = reversedWord[j];

    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(j, word[wordLength - 1 - j]);
    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(wordLength - 1 - j, temp);
  }
  return reversedWord;
}

function reverse() {
  let text = document.getElementById("text").value;

  let splittedText = text.split(" ");

  let reversedWords = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < splittedText.length; i++) {
    let word = splittedText[i];

    let reversedWord = reverseWord(word);
    reversedWords.push(reversedWord);
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reversedWords.join(" ");
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line of reverse() method and use `textContent` instead of value.

> let text = document.getElementById("text").textContent;

```js
document.getElementById("btnReverse").onclick = function () {
  reverse();
};

String.prototype.replaceAt = function (index, replacement) {
  if (index >= this.length) {
    return this.valueOf();
  }

  return this.substring(0, index) + replacement + this.substring(index + 1);
};

function reverseWord(word) {
  let wordLength = word.length;
  let reversedWord = word;
  for (let j = 0; j < wordLength / 2; j++) {
    let temp = reversedWord[j];
    let rightChar = word[wordLength - 1 - j];
    if(j === 0 && wordLength > 1 && word[j].toUpperCase() === word[j]) {
      temp = temp.toLowerCase();
      rightChar = rightChar.toUpperCase();
    }
    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(j, rightChar);
    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(wordLength - 1 - j, temp);
  }
  return reversedWord;
}

function reverse() {
  let text = document.getElementById("text").textContent;

  let splittedText = text.split(" ");
  let reversedWords = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < splittedText.length; i++) {
    let word = splittedText[i];

    let reversedWord = reverseWord(word);
    reversedWords.push(reversedWord);
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reversedWords.join(" ");
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>
<button id="btnReverse">Reverse</button>
<div id="text">I am A Great human</div>
<div id="demo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pictures
https://i.stack.imgur.com/19pZe.jpg

Sorry earlier Mr, the intention when input in the output form came out according to the capital requested for example in the example of the picture above, thank you for the response.

Demo : https://replit.com/join/jhnzimlcne-willyagustino

Comment: modified the code to handle capital case.

Answer (score 0):

This function re-capitalize a reversed word:

```
function reCapitalize(word) {  
    // Check if last letter is an uppercase
    // If so, return the word with first letter converted to capital
    if (word[word.length - 1] === word[word.length - 1].toUpperCase())
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.toLowerCase().substring(1, word.length);

   // return word unchanged
   return word;
}
```

So your reverse function will be like this:

```
function reverseWord(word) {
  let wordLength = word.length;
  let reversedWord = word;
  for (let j = 0; j < wordLength / 2; j++) {
    let temp = reversedWord[j];

    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(j, word[wordLength - 1 - j]);
    reversedWord = reversedWord.replaceAt(wordLength - 1 - j, temp);
  }
  return reCapitalize(reversedWord);
}
```

Comment: This overwrites in the reverse function of Mr? If you really, this solution I have tried but has not worked on my code, thank you for the response Mr.